# AWS CLI copy recursive command not copying files from S3 to local

Tags: docker, aws-cli

I'm trying to recursively copy S3 objects to my local directory, but when I do, nothing happens. No error message either.

Locally I use the `aws cli` via a temporary Docker container by adding the following to my `~/.bash_aliases` file:

```
alias aws="docker run --rm -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws -v $(pwd):/aws amazon/aws-cli
```

I `cd` into my local directory where I want the S3 objects to go to and I run:

```
aws s3 cp s3://myBucket/myFolder/ . --recursive
```

Ref: [https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/cp.html#:~:text=Recursively%20copying%20S3%20objects%20to%20a%20local%20directory](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/cp.html#:%7E:text=Recursively%20copying%20S3%20objects%20to%20a%20local%20directory)

Output:

```
download: s3://myBucket/myFolder/file1.xlsx to ./file1.xlsx
download: s3://myBucket/myFolder/file2.xlsx to ./file2.xlsx
download: s3://myBucket/myFolder/file3.xlsx to ./file3.xlsx
# ... etc etc
```

But when I go to my local current directory there's nothing there.

The `docker run` mounts a volume so it should in theory work?

Answer (score 0):

Read up answer in [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-docker.html#cliv2-docker-share-files-s3). The `aws` alias in `~/.bash_aliases` was missing the [interactive option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#assign-name-and-allocate-pseudo-tty---name--it) `-it`:

```
alias aws="docker run --rm -it -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws -v $(pwd):/aws amazon/aws-cli
```

Working successfully now.